# How to use interrupt handlers written in C in a C++ program?

Tags: c++, microcontroller, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I'm writing a program in C++ for my Tiva C Series board (EK-TM4C123GXL) and I'd like to use the [USB lib](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu297a/spmu297a.pdf) provided by TI to make it a device for another board.

I use the startup_gcc.c file provided [here](https://github.com/yuvadm/tiva-c/tree/master/boards/ek-tm4c123gxl/usb_dev_bulk).

Unfortunately, I cannot compile with those declarations :

```
extern void SysTickIntHandler(void);
extern void USB0DeviceIntHandler(void);
```

I get

```
(.isr_vector+0x3c):-1: error: undefined reference to `SysTickIntHandler'
```

I tried

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
void SysTickIntHandler(void);
void USB0DeviceIntHandler(void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

but nothing better.

Comment: Probably not because the TivaWare (tiva libraries) have `extern "C"` and I can use them in my C++ program if I don't use interrupt handlers.

Comment: Where is `SysTickIntHandler` defined?

Comment: Somewhere in the [System Tick](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu298a/spmu298a.pdf) library of TI.

Comment: do you link against this library?

Comment: Yes, using [CMake](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/345714dca75e0794d7ec) `${TIVAWARE_PATH}/driverlib/gcc/libdriver.a`.

Comment: You may need to have a [`naked` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AVR-Function-Attributes.html) placed with the function declaration.

Comment: I'm sorry but I found where that interrupt handler is located and it's completely useless for me. So I'll mark as solved. Thanks for your help :)